# Lists in Python => Javascript Translation

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7

```
for i in [name, matches_total, matches_won, matches_lost]:
    doSomething(i)
```

I tried doing this for JS but it did not work. Basically, I want it to do whatever it has to do over each of the variables. How do I do this with JS?

My attempt:

```
for (i in [name, matches_total, matches_won, matches_lost]){
    doSomething(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't have quite the same `in` operator. If you are in an environment that supports `forEach`, it's relatively close in style (except that you define an inner anonymous function for the loop, a bit like a Python `lambda`:

```
[name, matches_total, matches_won, matches_lost].forEach(function(i) {
    doSomething(i);
});
```

In this case (a case where you're calling a single function on each list item) you can simplify this in a way I find quite nice syntactically:

```
[name, matches_total, matches_won, matches_lost].forEach(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    doSomething(list[i]);
}
```

There are two kinds of for loops, the `for-in` loop designed for objects, and a three-statement for loop `for (;;)`. Using `for-in` on an array is not recommended, as it traverses its prototype chain as well.

Comment: @Zoidberg'-- In what way is it fixed?

Comment: `i` is index, not the element itself. Also the for loop itself was wrong.

Comment: @David: Zoidberg fixed the index vs. element issue. You fixed the off-by-one in his solution

Comment: @Zoidberg'-- Wrong. `i` was not the index but the last element in the array. I was traversing the array backwards. And your subsequent edit was wrong.

Comment: @David I was talking about your initial answer. I think we both edited it at the same time. I didn't notice the `--`, my bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_array = [name, matches_total, matches_won, matches_lost]

for (var i in my_array){
    doSomething(my_array[i]);
}
```